# Combining two lists, but not concatenating them

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
names = ['me', 'you', 'him', 'her']
scores = ['4', '7', '5', '6']
```

How do I combine them so that it makes one list?

```
combined = ['me: 4', 'you: 7', 'him: 5', 'her: 6']
```

Comment: Hint: [How can I iterate through two lists in parallel in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python)

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find anything when I ran a search, but now it works :)

Comment: >>> dict(zip(names,scores))
{'me': '4', 'you': '7', 'him': '5', 'her': '6'}